# Scrollable grid or table with top row and left column fixed in Ionic 3

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I need to implement a table or grid in Ionic, where the left column keeps fixed when the user scroll horizontally, but when the scroll is vertical, it should move. The top row must be similar, but it only moves with horizontal scroll and keeps fixed when the scroll is vertical.

Answer (score 0):

For a scrollable grid with top row fixed example:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    template: `
    <ion-header>
        <ion-navbar>
            <ion-title>Main Title</ion-title>
        </ion-navbar>

        <ion-toolbar mode="md" no-border-top>
            <ion-grid>
                <ion-row>
                    <ion-col col-2>Id</ion-col>
                    <ion-col col-2 text-right>Name</ion-col>
                </ion-row>
            </ion-grid>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content>
        <ion-grid>
            <ion-row *ngFor="let note of myData; let odd = odd" [ngClass]="{ 'table-background-row': odd}">
                <ion-col>
                    {{note?.id}}
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col>
                    {{note?.name}}
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>

        <ion-infinite-scroll>
            <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
        </ion-infinite-scroll>
    </ion-content>
`})

class myPage {
    @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

    myData: any;
    constructor(public platform: Platform, ) {
        this.toggleToolbar();
        this.myData = [{
            id: 1,
            name: "myName"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "yourName"
        }];
    });

    toggleToolbar() {
        this.content.resize();
    }
}
```

It might be helpfull for you :)

Comment: Thanks, but I also need that first column fixed, I need both, first column and first row fixed